# Replace a list item value with another list item value based on multiple condition

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have two list. ListA and ListB.

ListA

```
ID  Name    Age
001 Andy    null
002 Sam     null
```

ListB

```
ID  Name    Age
001 Andy    10
```

What I want to do is replace ListA's Age with ListB'Age based on two conditions using `Linq`. They are

```
ListA.ID == ListB.ID 
ListA.Name == ListB.Name
```

So, the final result would be:

```
ID  Name    Age
001 Andy    10
002 Sam     null
```

Please ignore column names because they are only for demo purpose.

Comment: The two conditions are disjunctive or conjuntive? (ie and, or, xor, ...)

Comment: Have to use 'and' @J.Salas

Answer (score 1):

You can work with Linq, the concept is `listA` LEFT JOIN `listB`.

```
var result = (from a in listA
            join b in listB on new { a.ID, a.Name } equals new { b.ID, b.Name } into ab
            from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new People
            {
                ID = a.ID,
                Name = a.Name,
                Age = b?.Age
            }
        ).ToList();
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hfK7Da)

Answer (score 1):

Given two list of items

```
List<ListItem> listA = new List<ListItem>();
List<ListItem> listB = new List<ListItem>();
```

of this type

```
    public class ListItem 
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? Age { get; set; }
    }
```

you can change all listA Age values this way:

```
listA.ForEach(item => 
    item.Age = listB.Where(itemB => itemB.ID == item.ID && itemB.Name == item.Name)
    .FirstOrDefault()?.Age);
```

Answer (score 0):

using foreach and linq

```
public class emp
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var ListA = new List<emp>();
    var ListB = new List<emp>();

    ListA.Add(new emp { ID = "001", Name = "Andy" });
    ListA.Add(new emp { ID = "002", Name = "Sam" });

    ListB.Add(new emp { ID = "001", Name = "Andy", Age = 10 });

    foreach (var emp in ListA)
    {
        var empfound = ListB.FirstOrDefault(lista => lista.ID == emp.ID);
        if (empfound != null) emp.Age = empfound.Age;
    }
}
```